# Фильтрация в rxjava по массиву

Tags: android, rxjava

Прошу помощи в решении такой проблемы. Есть модель:

```
public class User {

String name;
String gender;
String number;

public User(String name, String gender, String number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

Есть класс с данными:

```
public class DataSource {

public static List<User> createUser() {
    List<User> user = new ArrayList<>();
    user.add(new User("Alex", "male", "34"));
    user.add(new User("Helen", "female", "24"));
    user.add(new User("Ketti", "female", "18"));
    user.add(new User("Max", "male", "44"));
    user.add(new User("Pen", "male", "48"));
    return user;
}
```

И есть массив

```
String[] filterArray = {"Alex", "Helen", "Max"};
```

Помогите в этом коде

```
Observable<User> extractUser = Observable
            .fromIterable(DataSource.createUser())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .filter //Здесь нужна помощь

    extractUser.subscribe(new Observer<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(User user) {
            Log.d(TAG, user.getName() + ", " + user.getGender() + ", " + user.getNumber());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

произвести фильтрацию так, чтобы в результате вывелись данные, связанные с именами в массиве String[] filterArray

```
Alex, male, 34
Helen, female, 24
Max, male, 44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Преобразуйте список в отдельные элементы
2. Отфильтруйте их
3. Объедините обратно в список

```
.flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
.filter(user -> Arrays.asList(filterArray).contains(user.getName()))
.toList()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло.